# Visual Studio 2010 Setup Project: Overwrite a file even if it has changed?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project, orca

I have a Visual Studio 2010 Setup Project and I am trying to create an Upgrade to a new version of my software.

The upgrade process ***is*** running.  I properly updated the Version Number, which caused an update of the Product Code. RemovePreviousVersions is also True.

My problem is that when I upgrade my software, there is one file that may have changed on the local filesystem, in the course of running the software. I'm finding that, because the file changed, the installer refuses to overwrite it.
I want my installer to *force* this file to be overwritten with the new version.

Is there something I can do -- within Visual Studio, with Orca, or otherwise -- to force a file to be overwritten even if it has changed?

**UPDATE:** In Orca, I noticed that the "File" table includes a "FileSize" column. I believe this might be the reason the file is being ignored. If the size of the file has changed, it doesn't match. Is there any way to override this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't safely change the Windows Installer replace rules, but you are getting into this situation because the upgrade mechanism first installs the upgrade on top of the older product (invoking file replacement rules) then uninstalls the old product, ref counting down and removing the product. It's the "on top" that is the issue. If you move RemoveExistingProducts in the InstallExecuteSequence from just before InstallFinalize to just after InstallInitialize you will get a complete uninstall of the older product then the install of the new upgrade. That may not work if you are expecting to keep data files around.

Otherwise you could use the RemoveFile table with Orca. You'd add an entry targeting the Component name corresponding to the file (look in the File table, and there may already be some entries in the RemoveFile table as examples). You'd set the value to be Remove on Install. The RemoveFiles action occurs before the new files are installed, so it should work.

Comment: I did play around with the RemoveFile Table, and moving the RemoveExistingProducts step to earlier, but was getting either "no-change" or a sequencing error message. But putting RemoveExistingProducts in that exact spot seemed to do it!